# Heroku application crashed - No module names 'hjson'

Tags: python, json, heroku

I just installed hjson and imported it into my python application that is being held on a heroku server. After pushing the new updated code that imports hjson, my application crashed.

Here is the stack trace after running *heroku logs --tail*

```
import config, requests, hjson
2022-07-07T17:14:22.626278+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hjson'
```

Let me know if the entire stack trace is needed. Then was the only thing I could find that I understood.

**Where should I go from here? Is the error info I provided not enough to debug?**

Comment: This just means `hjson` _isn't installed_ (on the remote server; it might be installed locally on your workstation, but that doesn't help much). It's normal and expected that you can't use software you haven't installed.

Comment: Unfortunately I have restarted my machine as well as checked for the version installed which confirmed it has been installed.

Comment: What's installed on your machine doesn't matter. What your project tells heroko to install is what matters.

Comment: In general, it's a `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` file that's used to tell Heroku what to install.

Comment: Ah! I think this is the issue. I did not add it to my requirements.txt file. Charles, I appreciate the time you have taken to help me. I know it must be frustrating following these posts around to attempt to decipher my issues! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip, Heroku installs Python modules from a list in `requirements.txt`.

Make sure you add the library you're using for hjson to this list.