# re.sub to convert HJSON unquoted strings to valid JSON

Tags: python, json, post, python-re

I am receiving a POST request from a website with the following hjson.

```
{
    "passphrase": "123",
    "time": 2022-07-03T01:56:07Z,
    "ticker": AAPL,
    "orderAction": "buy"
}
```

As you can see, AAPL is not in quotations. I have provided my application below, in which you can see I have a json.loads call. I have tried to use hjson.loads instead but it caused my heroku application to crash for unknown reasons.

With that being said, my next step is to replace AAPL with "AAPL" using re.sub but I have not done it before and am very unfamiliar. **How can I use re.sub to surround AAPL with quotation marks?** It will not always be AAPL and could be any value of letters.

Code that receives this POST -> When receiving the hjson from above, it causes the application to stop running.

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
     webhook_message = json.loads(request.data)
     symbol = webhook_message['ticker']
```

Comment: `re.sub` is the wrong tool. Use the actual hjson parser.

Comment: I tried that but as I mentioned in the post above, using hjson causes an error in my heroku application. I cannot debug it so I have resulted to changing the JSON I receive using re.sub

Comment: If you can provide a [mre] letting us see that problem ourselves, we might be able to take a shot at fixing it. Much better to try to do the right thing before resorting to an ugly, fragile hack of a workaround.

Comment: This is as good of an example as I can give, you can look at my last post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901993/heroku-application-crashed-no-module-names-hjson to see how the hjson is causing issues. My application receives the POST just how I described above and then uses the info from the JSON, however everything done after the json.loads is not important

Comment: is it necessary to use regex? You can convert invalid json to a Python dict without using regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that any line of the form

```
"key": value,
```

where `value` isn't in quotes should have the value quoted, you can use:

```
data = re.sub(r'("[^"]+"):\s*([^"]+?)(,?)$', r'\1: "\2"\3', request.data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
webhook_message = json.loads(data)
```

`([^"]+?)` matches a sequence of characters not including `"`. The non-greedy quantifier is used so it won't include the optional comma at the end of the line.